# XStream OutOfMemoryError when generating xml

Tags: out-of-memory, xstream

I have a class defined to store configuration data for my application. I want to save the instances of this out to xml and use XStream for this. But I keep getting outofmemory errors when I try to write an instance.

Here is my class definition:

```
public class Eol_Target_Variable {
    String name;
    String alias;
    long value;
    long default_val;
    int size;
    int scaling;
    int div;
    Boolean read_access;
    Boolean write_access;


    public Eol_Target_Variable(String arg_name, String arg_alias, int arg_value, int arg_size, int arg_scaling,int arg_div)
    {
        name = arg_name;
        alias = arg_alias;
        value = arg_value;
        default_val = 0;
        scaling = arg_scaling;
        div = arg_div;
        size = arg_size;
        read_access = true;
        write_access = true;
    }
    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }


    /**
     * @param name the name to set
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
```

...etc for all standard getters and setters

Here is my handler for exporting a single object to xml

```
public void importConfiguration() {
    XStream xstream = new XStream(new DomDriver());
    Eol_Target_Variable myvar = new Eol_Target_Variable("jamie", "xtracold", 1977, 16, 1, 1);
    String myxml = xstream.toXML(myvar);
    System.out.print(myxml);
}
```

Every time I get "Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" thrown. I cannot see why such a simple class would throw the out of memory error. I have managed to output simple String objects using XStream so the library is working, it is just this custom class that seems to cause problems.

I have also tried to increase the heap allocated at startup with the VM arguments -Xms512m -Xmx1024m but that makes no difference.

Thanks
Jamie

Comment: I've now made some progress. I think the problem was recursion on the class that resulted in the whole JavaFX scene graph being parsed. That was one problem. The other was that my data structures include reference to the graphic Node to on which the data is graphically represented. What I have now done is moved my class declaration to separate files and also suppressed the inclusion of the Nodes in the XML.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the new class declaration

```
@XStreamAlias("targetVar")
public class Eol_Target_Variable {
    String name;
    String alias;
    long value;
    @XStreamAlias("default")
    long default_val;
    int size;
    int scaling;
    int div;
    @XStreamOmitField
    Node node;
    @XStreamOmitField
    Boolean read_access;
    @XStreamOmitField
    Boolean write_access;


public Eol_Target_Variable(String arg_name, String arg_alias, int arg_value, int arg_size, int arg_scaling,int arg_div,  Node arg_node)
{
    name = arg_name;
    alias = arg_alias;
    value = arg_value;
    default_val = 0;
    scaling = arg_scaling;
    div = arg_div;
    size = arg_size;
    node = arg_node;
    read_access = true;
    write_access = true;
}
```

I also used a different parser as the basic DOMParser never handled the massive amount of data. When I changed to StaxDriver was at least able to see the streams of text in the debug output as XStream traversed the whole scene graph.

```
XStream xstream = new XStream(new StaxDriver());
xstream.processAnnotations(Eol_Target_Variable.class);
```

I don't pretend to fully understand why declaring the class inlined causes problems, but I can reason as to why asking XStream to parse a complete Node might cause issues.

If anyone has any experience with XStream and complex data structures, that are declared inside a JavaFX app I would welcome their input.